# difference between int* member[0] and int member[0] in struct

Tags: c

```
struct A {
  int zero_member[0];
  int other;
};

struct B {
  int* zero_member_ptr[0];
  int other;
};

printf("%d %d", sizeof(struct A), sizeof(struct B));
```

Output:

```
4 8
```

Why the difference?

In reality I'm using this with Android NDK, and I've tested it at [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/n6b6sf8s4) without any flag. So, if this is not standard ISO C program, this problem should have no standard answer.

Comment: What compiler and flags are you using? GCC, Clang, and MSVC all emit some variant of "ISO C forbids zero-size array " or "struct 'A' has an illegal zero-sized array" for that code.

Comment: Neither one is valid C, so in that sense there is no difference at all.  If your C implementation accepts those as an extension, then their significance is implementation-specific.

Comment: beng in, `sizeof` returns a `size_t`.  Use `"%zu"` to match.

Comment: GNU99 you can have a zero-length array as the last member, however this is subsumed by the [FAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Why the difference?"

Likely due to padding to meet pointer alignment requirements - even if it is size 0.